# (Request.IsAuthenticated) is false after using FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username,false)

Tags: forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I am building a website with VS2013 RC and MVC 5 and am trying to use formsAuthentification without registering permanent users on my site.

I'm posting to my company's api to authenticate user's names and passwords.  When this comes back successfully, I want to issue an authorization cookie with:

```
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
```

I see the .ASPXAUTH=... cookie after this is called.

But, I can not get into the @if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) or alternatively @if(Request.IsAuthenticated) block on the template's _LoginPartial.cshtml page.

This technique did work for me in MVC 4 and I am trying to bend it to fit MVC 5's OWIN authentication.

Comment: The answer is fine, but I think this problem is unrelated to MVC 5, as I got the same issue in MVC 4.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I needed to enable forms authentication in the web.config

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
...
</system.web>
```

Comment: I got same problem ! add your answer to web.config works fine ! request.IsAuthenticated returns true

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to fight against MVC5 new authentication mode (OWIN) you can find your answer in this link

http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/asp-net-mvc-5-authentication-breakdown-part-deux#disqus_thread

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above solutions ,but the thing that solves my problem was commenting this in web.config

```
<modules>
<remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
</modules>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those who still have this issue and have tried all above approaches I do recommend try add to the Web.Config file in the section authentication forms cookieless="UseCookies". In my case it worked fine.

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
...
</system.web>
```